# Is there a way to detect if the device is a VR HEADSET and not just a "VR allowed" device?

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality

I've been searching but I couldn't find... I'm making a three js webgl VR experience but I don't want the VR to be accessible on mobile phones, ONLY on VR headsets.

For the moment I only can detect if the device is able to use VR, but many mobiles are, and I don't want those to allow VR. I've been searching but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd purposely prevent certain users from accessing the content if they can handle it. But if you really want to exclude mobile devices, you're gonna have to target a specific functionality of theirs. For example, you can disable it if it has [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchstart_event):

```js
button.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    // Disable your app however you please
    app.disabled = true;
});
```

Keep in mind this isn't 100% foolproof because some devices could *pretend* to have touch events, but it can get you pretty close.